# Самопроизвольное изменение яркости экрана ноутбука Manjaro Linux KDE

Tags: linux, kde, manjaro

Во время работы за ноутбуком появляется ползунок изменения яркости и происходит само изменение как будто нажали на клавиатуре клавишу. Причем она меняется как вверх так и вниз. Один раз удалось поймать в htop через фильтр изменение яркости. Никаких дополнительных настроек по управлению яркостью через питание нет. В Linux не совсем новичок, подскажите куда копать?

[image: скриншот htop]

Comment: возможно на ноуте есть датчик освещенности.

Comment: Проверил, точно нет.